# Testes com certificados digitais

Tags: testes, certificado-digital, assinatura-digital

Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece uma forma de realizar testes com certificados digitais.

Estou com a seguinte situação, meu sistema funciona normalmente com certificados digitais. Entretanto quando o certificado configurado vence ou no caso de certificados token, não esta devidamente instalado na máquina o sistema apresenta alguns erros.
Precisaria de certificados digitais para testes. Inválidos, vencidos, válidos... Isso seria possível ou estou querendo muito?

Comment: Qual linguagem? eu sei que com .net é possível

Comment: Informe mais detalhes, o que você precisa fazer, qual serviço está trabalhando exemplo: POP, IMAP , qual a linguagem ?

Comment: O sistema está em pascal. Não estou trabalhando com envio de e-mail, mas o sistema utiliza o certificado digital para assinar e enviar documentos para um servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para um certificado inválido é fácil, basta criar um certificado auto-assinado, com algumas variações, como por exemplo, um nome de domínio errado. Quanto a certificados válidos em dia e vencidos, a melhor forma é (apenas em seu ambiente de testes) você ser uma autoridade certificadora.

Você pode então criar certificados válidos (no contexto de seu ambiente) em dia e vencidos, além dos inválidos.

Aqui tem um artigo sobre isso:

http://eriberto.pro.br/wiki/index.php?title=Autoridade_Certificadora_(CA)_com_o_OpenSSL